# Ionic app halts at splash screen when running with ‘–prod’ build

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I've been working on an app which consists of "in-app purchases", "firebase dynamic links", etc. The app works fine in both Android and iOS, when I used to run the app using commands:

```
ionic cordova run android
ionic cordova build ios
```

But as soon as I run the app using '--prod' in front of them the app used to get stuck on my splash screen/app.component.ts screen.

Some of my app's structure looks like this:

**config.xml**

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.ionic.wordforyou" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>WordForYou</name>
    <description>An awesome Ionic/Cordova app.</description>
    <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Ionic Framework Team</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="70000" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <platform name="android">
        <preference name="GoogleAndroidClientId" value="some_id_here" />
        <resource-file src="google-services.json" target="google-services.json" />
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <preference name="GoogleIOSClientId" value="some_id_here" />
        <resource-file src="GoogleService-Info.plist" />
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
    </platform>
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.0.181:8100" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.1.133:8100" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.0.180:8100" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="~4.5.4" />
    <engine name="android" spec="~6.3.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" spec="^2.2.1" />
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="^2.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^1.1.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^4.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^1.1.16" />
    <plugin name="cc.fovea.cordova.purchase" spec="^7.1.2">
        <variable name="BILLING_KEY" value="some_key_here" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-support-google-services" spec="^1.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks" spec="^0.12.1">
        <variable name="APP_DOMAIN" value="waa24.app.goo.gl" />
        <variable name="APP_PATH" value="/" />
        <variable name="FIREBASE_VERSION" value="11.0.+" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" spec="^5.3.2" />
</widget>
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
@Component({
templateUrl: 'app.html',
providers: [
    InAppPurchase2,
    HomeService,
    AuthService,
]
})
export class MyApp {
@ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

rootPage: any;
showStartupScreen: Boolean = true;
public tempRootPage: any;
public hasFirebaseDynamicLink: Boolean = false;

constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    statusBar: StatusBar,
    splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private store: InAppPurchase2,
    // private deeplinks: Deeplinks,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private homeService: HomeService,
    private singletonService: SingletonService,
    private storage: Storage,
    private events: Events,
    private toast: Toast,
    private firebaseDynamicLinks: FirebaseDynamicLinks,
) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
    // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
    // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
    statusBar.styleDefault();
    splashScreen.hide();
    this._initIap();
    // this._initDeeplinks();
    this._handleEvents();
    this._initServerCalls();
    });
}
...
```

In ios I'm getting the logs:

```js
2018-03-11 09:41:33.332179+0530 WordForYou[1159:183502] DiskCookieStorage changing policy from 2 to 0, cookie file: file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C577545E-13A7-4C2F-86D7-F3D3D2A74A2E/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies
2018-03-11 09:41:33.428318+0530 WordForYou[1159:183502] Apache Cordova native platform version 4.5.3 is starting.
2018-03-11 09:41:33.430405+0530 WordForYou[1159:183502] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2018-03-11 09:41:33.473991+0530 WordForYou[1159:183502] CDVWKWebViewEngine: trying to inject XHR polyfill
2018-03-11 09:41:33.847546+0530 WordForYou[1159:183502] CDVWKWebViewEngine will reload WKWebView if required on resume
2018-03-11 09:41:33.847717+0530 WordForYou[1159:183502] Using Ionic WKWebView
2018-03-11 09:41:33.849899+0530 WordForYou[1159:183502] [CDVTimer][console] 0.231028ms
2018-03-11 09:41:33.850581+0530 WordForYou[1159:183502] [CDVTimer][handleopenurl] 0.357032ms
2018-03-11 09:41:33.856422+0530 WordForYou[1159:183502] [CDVTimer][intentandnavigationfilter] 5.723953ms
2018-03-11 09:41:33.856731+0530 WordForYou[1159:183502] [CDVTimer][gesturehandler] 0.190973ms
2018-03-11 09:41:33.871924+0530 WordForYou[1159:183502] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2018-03-11 09:41:33.872972+0530 WordForYou[1159:183502] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.
2018-03-11 09:41:33.877654+0530 WordForYou[1159:183502] InAppPurchase[objc] Initialized.
2018-03-11 09:41:33.877766+0530 WordForYou[1159:183502] [CDVTimer][inapppurchase] 20.957947ms
2018-03-11 09:41:33.901254+0530 WordForYou[1159:183502] [CDVTimer][splashscreen] 23.403049ms
2018-03-11 09:41:33.903321+0530 WordForYou[1159:183502] [CDVTimer][keyboard] 1.774073ms
2018-03-11 09:41:33.903649+0530 WordForYou[1159:183502] Starting Firebase DynamicLinks plugin
2018-03-11 09:41:33.903767+0530 WordForYou[1159:183502] [CDVTimer][firebasedynamiclinks] 0.256062ms
2018-03-11 09:41:33.904093+0530 WordForYou[1159:183502] [CDVTimer][socialsharing] 0.259042ms
2018-03-11 09:41:33.904176+0530 WordForYou[1159:183502] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 55.562019ms
2018-03-11 09:41:33.911672+0530 WordForYou[1159:183545] [MC] Filtering mail sheet accounts for bundle ID: io.ionic.wordforyou, source account management: 1
2018-03-11 09:41:33.922380+0530 WordForYou[1159:183545] [MC] Result: YES
2018-03-11 09:41:33.922951+0530 WordForYou[1159:183545] [MC] Filtering mail sheet accounts for bundle ID: io.ionic.wordforyou, source account management: 1
2018-03-11 09:41:33.924259+0530 WordForYou[1159:183545] [MC] Result: YES
2018-03-11 09:41:34.335772+0530 WordForYou[1159:183502] InAppPurchase[objc] (before init): WARNING: Your app should be single page to use in-app-purchases. onReset is not supported.
```

My `ionic info` prints this:

```js
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.5
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0 ios 4.5.4
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    ios-deploy : 1.9.2
    Node       : v6.11.3
    npm        : 3.10.10
    OS         : macOS High Sierra
    Xcode      : Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

My chrome inspector showing me this log (in dev mode only, by the way my app is working with this log - this is only for your information)

[image: dev debug log for android]

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run it on what adroid version?
I am asking this because Ionic 3 does not support all android versions.From my experience, 4.4 and up can run well, but lower versions had this kind of problem.

Also, before you start doing --prod and --release clean up (delete files) under platform/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release and platform/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug

Than run your --prod or --release

Comment: I'm running it on Android version 6.0, I've done everything you've mentioned, but still, my app isn't working on both the platforms. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Can you try to add this:`<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="2000"/>
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="2000"/>
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false"/>
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />` to your config.xml